# delay inside while loop not working

Tags: java, android, multithreading, delay

i'm trying to make a delay inside while loop using Thread.sleep() method . here is my code :

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            z=0;
                        while (z<45){
                            z++;

                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    time.setText(Integer.toString(45-z));


                                }
                            });

                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                            }



                        }


                    }
                }).start();
```

this code was working and suddenly a problem occurred . it started to make a delay less than one minute , sumtimes 500 ms and sumtimes less than that

Comment: What is the console output?

Comment: do you mean Log ? i tried that and same result it makes a delay less than one second.

Comment: how are you timing it?

Comment: i used Log to compare this application to another application (working fine) and i realized that for every 1 second log in working app there is 2 logs in this app so it is 500 ms, also it is obvious on screen that the delay is less than 1 second

Comment: Try using system.currentTimeMillis to time it and print it out to the console

Comment: here is the result : 1499970282536
1499970282660
1499970282797

Comment: While you can make your outer thread sleep for a specific duration, you cannot guarantee when how the threads will be executed or sequenced.  Put a logger just before `handler.post` and time the difference between the logs.

Comment: Also put a log InterruptedException catch to see if some external interrupt is causing the thread to wake up.

Answer (score 1):

Instead if using a different thread, Thread.sleep(), Handler and while loop you can try only with Handler like this,

```
private int timerCount = 0;

private static Handler myHandler = new Handler();

private void runVVRunnable() {
    myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        timerCount++;

        if ((time == null)) {
            return;
        }

        if (timerCount <= 45) {
            time.setText(Integer.toString(timerCount));

            runVVRunnable();
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    myHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}
```

you can just call `runVVRunnable()` it will do the same process which you are doing while loop

Comment: it is not working , same result with my original code , ++ i have tried a sample application from android studio and it worked fine so the problem is not with the code , but what do you think can cause this behaviour in my application ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but when sleeping/waiting on Java thread you need to try-catch `InterruptedException`.

This exception is thrown when "someone" calls `interrupt()` on your thread.

This will cause the thread to wake up from sleep early than expected.

Check if you catch `InterruptedException` before your thread terminated.

Comment: You made sure this exception is not thrown? Like putting a break point on  e.printStackTrace(); inside the catch block?